# Recommended way to read from socket in HTTP server

Tags: java, http, sockets, networking, tcp

As a challenge I have implemented a basic web server in Java. When I open the raw `InputStream` I immediately go into a blocking read which reads the entire 400 or bytes of the HTTP request into a byte array. This works, however I then do not check for any more data and simply close the socket after sending a response.

I'm wondering is there a more robust way to do this so as not to miss any data from the client. I thought of reading one byte at a time until `read` returned end of stream. However it instead sometimes blocks when there is no more data and confusingly the JavaDocs for `public abtract int InputStream.read()` says:

`If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.`

So it implies that two things can happen if the end of stream is reached: returning -1 and blocking. I am seeing blocking.

*My question is, with a protocol like HTTP, how should you read from the socket and how do you know when that's all the data you'll be getting in this connection?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JavaDoc you quote does **not** imply that two things can happen if the end of stream is reached. It doesn't say read blocks **when** the end of the stream is detected, but **until** the end of stream is detected. Once it is detected, -1 is returned.

This explains the behavior you're observing: no end of stream is detected and read is blocked. The end of stream is detected once the connection is closed, but it isn't closed since the client doesn't close the connection immediately after sending a request. It must keep it open to receive the reply.

In order to ensure you receive all data from the client you should parse their HTTP request until you see the end of header (double newline) plus whatever amount of data they have specified in the header (if any).

If you'd like to avoid blocking have a look at [`java.nio`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) and [channels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html#multiplex) ([`SocketChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) in particular).

Comment: There is no alternative to implementing the HTTP protocol. The HTTP protocol tells you how to identify the end of a request. You should keep reading until you get an entire request.

Comment: Precisely, there is no way to determine whether a client has sent all data they wanted to send referring to transport layer facilities only. Application layer must be called upon to answer this question.

Comment: Nice explanation. It makes sense now. So would you read one byte at a time until you reach the end of header?

Comment: Nope. Read as much as your buffer takes and parse the partial request. Incremental parser will help here a lot. Continue reading and parsing until the parser determines that no more data is expected. Then process the request, send a reply and close (provided the connection isn't to be kept alive).

Comment: Follow this logic: 1) If you have a complete request, stop reading and process it. 2) Read as many bytes as you can get in one call to your read/receive function, adding them to the bytes you already have, if any. 3) Go to step 1. (This is part of what it means to implement a protocol!)

Comment: @David I'd like to write the code to cater for my byte buffer being smaller than an entire request (again, for the challenge). I think Adams advice  is different than yours? He implies parse as you go, through a small buffer. Are you implying the read is split only because of client delay and that that the server buffer is large enough to hold any request data?

Comment: @ScrollerBlaster You can parse as you go if you want. The advantages and disadvantages of both approaches are numerous and, generally, pretty slight. To some extent, you have to parse as you go because you need to parse the headers to know if there's a request body and, if so, how big it is. When I say "If you have a complete request", that determination can include parsing newly-arrived data.

Comment: @David.You didn't answer the question at the end of my comment :-).