# Proxy in Java - client not displaying response?

Tags: java, sockets, http, proxy

My programming assignment requires me to create a proxy in between client and server. 
My client make a request to server through the proxy, then the proxy forwards it and returns back the response from the server to the client.

Here's the steps I took:

1) get request from client and store the request data into a byte array

2) read from the byte array using buffered reader

3) get the host name from the Host: header field and create a serverSocket with it

4) forward the request data to the serverSocket outputstream

5) retrieve the response data from the serverSocket inputstream into another byte array

6) write contents from the byte array into clientSocket output stream

However, after step 6, the browser is unable to display the response data. Any help?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class proxy2 {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    File fileSub= new File(args[1]); //fileSub
    File fileRediect = new File(args[2]); //fileRedirect

    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);


    while (true) {
      proxy_func(listener.accept());

    }

  }

  public static void proxy_func(Socket clientSocket) throws Exception{

    OutputStream outputToClient = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

    //store clientSocket's inputstream into a buffer
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int nRead; //start offset in the data
    byte[] data = new byte[16384]; //create byte array
    //read each byte from InputStream and write it to a ByteArrayOutputStream
    while((nRead = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
      buffer.write(data, 0, nRead); 
    }
    buffer.flush(); //forces any buffered bytes to be written out
    data = buffer.toByteArray(); //retrieve the underlying byte array 
    System.out.println(new String(data));

    //create buffer reader for clientSocket's inputstream
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BufferedReader readFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String[] strArr;
    String line;
    String hostname = null;

    //get hostname
    while(  (line=readFromClient.readLine()) != null)
    {
      strArr = line.split(" ");
      if(strArr[0].equals("Host:"))
        hostname = strArr[1];
    }
    System.out.println("Host: " + hostname);

    //create server socket
    Socket serverSocket = new Socket(hostname, 80);
    OutputStream outputToServer = serverSocket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inputFromServer = serverSocket.getInputStream();

    //forward request to server
    System.out.println("forward request to server...");
    outputToServer.write(data);

    //receive data from server and write response back to client
    byte[] receivedData = new byte[16384];
    int size;
    while((size = inputFromServer.read(receivedData)) != -1)
    {
      System.out.println("write response back to client...");
      System.out.println("size: " + size);
      System.out.println(new String(receivedData));
      outputToClient.write(receivedData, 0, size);
    }

    System.out.println("flushing...");
    outputToClient.flush();
    outputToClient.close();
  }
}
```

So basically I follow this layout for the I/O:

```
{
    OutputStream outputToClient = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    BufferedReader readFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    //step 1
    //get the HTTP request header from your firefox
    String line = readFromClient.readLine();

    //if the Content_Length within the HTTP header exists and not equals to 0
    char [] buffer = new char [#];
    readFromClient.read(buffer, 0, Content_Length); //get the body message

    OutputStream outputToServer = serverSocket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inputFromServer = serverSocket.getInputStream();
    //step 2
    outputToServer.write(Bytes[])  //forword the HTTP requests to server host.

    //step 3
    byte[] data = new byte[#];
    while ((size = inputFromServer.read(data)) != -1)   //get the response data from server
    {
        //step 4
        outputToClient.write(data, 0, size);    //forward the data to your firefox
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the cause of the problem. My while loop got blocked because I didn't detect the end of HTTP request. This answer addresses my problem succintly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9542710

Just posting here for those who stumbled upon this problem and got lost.

Here's my updated code which can work (notice that I added a method to detect end of HTTP request):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class proxy2 {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    File fileSub= new File(args[1]); //fileSub
    File fileRediect = new File(args[2]); //fileRedirect

    //create listener socket to listen for requests from browser
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);

    while (true) {
      proxy_func(listener.accept());
    }

  }

  public static void proxy_func(Socket clientSocket) throws Exception{

    OutputStream outputToClient = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inputFromClient = clientSocket.getInputStream();

    //store clientSocket's inputstream into a buffer

    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int nRead; //start offset in the data
    byte[] data = new byte[16384]; 
    //read each byte from InputStream and write it to a ByteArrayOutputStream
    while((nRead = inputFromClient.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
      System.out.println("reading from client...");
      buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
      //if reached end of HTTP request, break out of this loop
      if(endOfRequest(data) == true)
        break;
    }
    buffer.flush(); //forces any buffered bytes to be written out
    data = buffer.toByteArray(); //retrieve the underlying byte array 
    System.out.println(new String(data));

    //create buffered reader for byte array input stream (request data)
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BufferedReader readFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String[] strArr;
    String line;
    String hostname = null;

    //get hostname
    while(  (line=readFromClient.readLine()) != null)
    {
      strArr = line.split(" ");
      if(strArr[0].equals("Host:"))
        hostname = strArr[1];
    }
    System.out.println("Host: " + hostname);

    //create server socket
    Socket serverSocket = new Socket(hostname, 80);
    OutputStream outputToServer = serverSocket.getOutputStream();
    //InputStream inputFromServer = serverSocket.getInputStream();

    //forward request to server
    System.out.println("forward request to server...");
    outputToServer.write(data);

    //receive data from server and write response back to client
    DataInputStream inputFromServer = new DataInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream());
    byte[] receivedData = new byte[1024];
    int size;
    while((size = inputFromServer.read(receivedData, 0, receivedData.length)) != -1)
    {
      System.out.println("write response back to client...");
      System.out.println(new String(receivedData));
      outputToClient.write(receivedData, 0, size);
      outputToClient.flush();
    }

    System.out.println("done sending");
    outputToClient.close();
  }

  //method to detect end of HTTP request
  //return true if detected, otherwise false
  public static boolean endOfRequest(byte[] data) throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println("parsing request..");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)));
    String line;

    while( (line=br.readLine()) != null) {
      if (line.equals(""))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the last part:

```
byte[] receivedData = new byte[16384];
int size;
while((size = inputFromServer.read(receivedData)) != -1)
{
  System.out.println("write response back to client...");
  System.out.println("size: " + size);
  System.out.println(new String(receivedData));
}
outputToClient.write(receivedData);
```

So, let's say the server sends back 1 million bytes. The loop reads them by chunks of 16384 bytes, and once it has read all the chunks, it sends back what has been left in the `receivedData` buffer by the after the last read. So the browser will only receive 16384 bytes among the 1,000,000 bytes sent by the server.

You must send everything you read from the server to the browser:

```
byte[] receivedData = new byte[16384];
int size;
while((size = inputFromServer.read(receivedData)) != -1)
{
  System.out.println("write response back to client...");
  System.out.println("size: " + size);
  System.out.println(new String(receivedData));
  outputToClient.write(receivedData, 0, size);      
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. Actually I implemented your approach before but it didn't work. I updated my answer with your edited code. Do you know any other ways to make this work?

Comment: Define "didn't work". What happens. What do your logs say? What do you see the Firebug network console?

Comment: I can see the printed response data on the console(I ran using cmd), but my browser is unable to display the response data, i.e. it is still waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this all wrong. An HTTP proxy only has to read the CONNECT command, and action it. After that, you just copy bytes in both directions simultaneously as fast as possible. The more you try to understand the HTTP protocol in the proxy, the more bugs you will introduce.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the anwser about how to read all data from a request.

I try your answer and  use postman to post a http request.
when http body data less than 16384(because `byte[] data = new byte[16384]`)
it works well. when request body data larger than it, it will lose some data.

it reappeared when i try to change the code `byte[] data = new byte[2]`, and set request body ({
aaa

})
witch body data with blank and new line.
and i post a request then i lose all the body data.
Because function `endOfRequest(byte[] data)` think request data gets to end, and the code jump out the while loop.

later I saw the http Protocol, it use a empty line to separate request header and request body.
and in the header  "Content-Length" mark the length of  body data.
So the better solution is that  find the request body and read the content-length data instead of using method endOfRequest() to jump out the while loop.